# Detecting "♪" in String

Tags: python, string, character, ascii

I'm really sorry if this has been posted before but I simply can't find the answer online.

I am reading in subtitles and wish to exclude the theme song/ending. They are denoted at the beginning of a line with the "♪" symbol. I tried to use the ASCII value and the chr() command but was unable to get it working.

If someone could post a way to see when the "♪" symbol is in a string it would be much appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you able to show us what code you are using at the moment?

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: U use python 3? Is so, you can just do `a="♪gfdgsdfghgfh"; a.startswith("♪")`. In p3, string are unicode.

Comment: '\xe2\x99\xaa' is the Unicode escape for your character

Comment: From this site http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/266a/index.htm, I have python u"\u266A". I assume u is short for unicode and the quotations are the unicode code. I put this in chr() to see if it is a line as so


if (chr(u"\u266A") in line):
 print line

To see if I can register it, but I cannot.

Comment: @Marcin I guess I am not using python 3 because your method unfortunately does not work. If I don't find a solution though I will upgrade and use your method. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MrBrightside Can you provide example code. Why it does not work? Any errors? Example input and expected output?

Comment: @jakekimds : no, that is the character `♪` encoded as UTF-8. `b'\xe2\x99\xaa'.decode('utf8')` is `u'\u266a'`.

Comment: @mhawke Sorry, new to the Unicode, UTF and that kind of thing.

Comment: You are reading them in *from a file*? Then you **must** know the encoding of the file and open it accordingly. There are no substitutes for a proper understanding: http://bit.ly/unipain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the lines in the input subtitle file and write those lines that do not begin with `u'\u266a'` (♪) to the output file.

For Python 2 & 3:

```
with open('file.srt') as subs, open('outfile.srt', 'w') as out:
    for line in subs:
        if not line.startswith(u'\u266a'):
            out.write(line)
```

If you want to find lines that contain ♪ anywhere, just use `in`:

```
if not u'\u266a' in line:
```

This, of course, will remove *all* lines that begin with ♪, not just those in the song ending. And it may not even be effective because different subtitle file formats do things differently. To remove only those subtitle lines requires knowledge of the time range that the theme song is played, and this requires knowledge of the subtitle file format since time codes representations vary. For example, SRT files contain multiple lines for each subtitle like this:

```
3
00:01:25,640 --> 00:01:27,510
Go any deeper...

4
00:01:28,160 --> 00:01:29,700
.. we die.
```

So now you need to detect the lines that begin with ♪, then backup and remove the preceeding 2 lines, and remove the following line. I am no expert on the file format.... the first line looks like a sequence number and I don't know whether it must be contiguous. In cases like this is is often easier to read the whole file into a list, and then process the list.

Anyway, now you know how to detect lines that begin with a specific unicode character, so you can proceed from that.

Comment: A quick test of an SRT file shows that, at least for mplayer, removing the subtitle text line only, and leaving the preceding lines in place works - effectively its a blank subtitle.

Answer (score 0):

"♪" is not in the ASCII character set. It is in the font used on the IBM PC at position 13 (0x0D). In the unicode character set it's at position 0x266A, so in Python you can use `u"\u266A"`. If you specify the encoding of your source file you can just include any character in the string:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print("♪")
```

Note that there is an other issue: python raises an exception if the output code page can't encode that character:

`print("\u266A")`

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u266a' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>`

If you want to print to the console, in python 3.4 (maybe earlier, but not in python 2.7) you can solve this by changing the code page (eg. execute `chcp 65001`) before starting your program.

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_music_in_string(my_string):
    for char in my_string:
        if ord(char) == 9834:
            print 'i have found you ' + char

find_music_in_string(u'\u266a')
```

`ord()` gets the int value of a char, the value of ♪ is 9832.

Comment: Use `in` rather than looping in Python. And you don't need to use `ord()`... just use `u"\u266a"`, i.e. `if u'\u266a' in my_string: print  u'i have found you \u266a'`

Comment: @mhawke Is there a way to modify the char at some point? Is not only to find if you have '♪'.

Comment: In your code there is no way to modify the character that is being searched for. If you want that, pass it to the function as an argument, then you can do: `if char in my_string: print u'i have found you {}'.format(char)`